# I wanted to develop a webpage which gives an output as mention in the description

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea in HTML if i paste contents of one column of excel .Supoose for example:

```
JSJYJ47    
JSJYJ48    
JSJYJ49    
JSJYJ50    
JSJYJ51    
JSJYJ52    
JSJYJ53    
JSJYJ54    
JSJYJ55    
JSJYJ56    
JSJYS00
```

i should get output with no **spaces and enter**:

```
JSJYJ45,JSJYJ47,JSJYJ48,JSJYJ49,JSJYJ50,JSJYJ51,JSJYJ52,JSJYJ53,JSJYJ54,JSJYJ55,JSJYJ56,JSJYS00,JSTAA36
```

Also i need to place comma by user specified number if i say 8 character so after each 8 character the comma should be place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all new newlines and whitespaces. Then after every x characters break the string and then join it with the character you want.

```js
$(function(){
  $('textarea').on('blur', function(){
      var val = $('textarea').val();
      var string  = val.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").replace(/ /g,'');
      var ret = [];
      var n = parseInt($('#selOpt').val(), 10);
      for(i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i += n) {
       ret.push(string.substr(i, n))
    }

    console.log(ret.join(','));
    $('#setHere').text(ret.join(','))
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="comment" placeholder="Enter text here" rows="10"></textarea>
<div>
<select id="selOpt">
   <option value = "1" >1</option>
   <option value = "2" >2</option>
   <option value = "3" >3</option>
   <option value = "4" >4</option>
   <option value = "5" >5</option>
   <option value = "6" >6</option>
</select>
 </div>
<div id="setHere"></div>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('textarea').on('blur', function(){
      var val = $('textarea').val();
      var string = val.replace(/ /g, '').split(/[\n\r]/g);
      
      $('#setHere').text(string);
    });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="comment" placeholder="Enter text here" rows="10"></textarea>
<div>
<select id="selOpt">
   <option value = "1" >1</option>
   <option value = "2" >2</option>
   <option value = "3" >3</option>
   <option value = "4" >4</option>
   <option value = "5" >5</option>
   <option value = "6" >6</option>
</select>
 </div>
<div id="setHere"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of getting output in console if i wanted output to display on the page how can i display it on the page.
And you have mentioned after every 8 character comma should be placed but if i wanted a user defined number how could i select it .

Comment: @anishshah If you want it to be customized then you can have a dropdown from which you can select the number of characters after which you want to have the `,` and then get its val in `var n` . If you wanna put the value in some div then select that div and then use `$('div').text(ret.join(',')`

Comment: @anishshah edited my sinppet have a look

Comment: thanks a lot the code work but the  code doesn't work if i have two words of different length and if i have a set of words with different  length than the words should be separated by the comma . Can you pls help on this
eg : if i have JSJDF59 (7 character)and i have JSJD456(8 charater) the out i am getting is JSJDF59,JSJDF45,6  Can you help me on this pls.

Comment: Added the code for the requirement

Comment: i have changed the code pls check it out .
the problem i was facing in the previous code was i was getting to many comma between two words if there were too many spaces . i wanted only a single comma between two words .

Comment: @anishshah Your are right. Go ahead with the current code. Also mark the answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: if i have to make the code a generic code ,i.e if user want the code to be seperated by semicolon,colon etc i mean all type of seperator .Depending upon the user input can i get the desire output and the input will be given in the input text area.The desire output need to be saved in which ever format he want . We will include a save as button for saving the file.

Comment: @anishshah yes you can, just get the value in a variable and perform join with that operator.

Comment: i have added the code pls check it and let me know it not working

Answer (score 0):

- Trim the unneccessary spaces
- Split the string based on new line.
- Join them using a comma.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = $("#txtField").val();
    parts = str.replace(/ /g, '').split(/[\n\r]/g);
    console.log(parts.join(','))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='txtField'>
JSJYJ47    
JSJYJ48    
JSJYJ49    
JSJYJ50    
JSJYJ51    
JSJYJ52    
JSJYJ53    
JSJYJ54    
JSJYJ55    
JSJYJ56    
JSJYS00
</textarea>
```

Comment: Please don't answer "write this for me" questions.

Comment: Yeah this was too elementary, but on other thought he might have issues with regex. Would keep in mind.